# Who is Hanazawa Hanako?

Tags: oregairu

I was rewatching the first season of Oregairu the other day, and something caught my eye on the list of contacts on Hachiman's phone (which we see in episode 5, after Yui adds herself as a contact).

[image: screen one] [image: screen two]

The list here is:

- Komachi
- Grandpa's
- Home
- Soubu High School
- Takatsu Dentistry
- Dad
- Barbershop
- **Hanazawa Hanako** (花沢華子)
- Mom
- ✨✨Yui✨✨

So we have Hachiman's relatives; places he goes (school, dentist, barber); and now Yui. But who is Hanazawa Hanako? That's a girl's name - but why would Hachiman have a girl's number in his phone?

Comment: Scanned through Japanese Wikipedia. Can't find her name listed in the list of characters, so I guess she is not someone crucial to the plot (for now). This is also discovered by several Japanese blog posts, though I can't find any answer as to who she is.

Answer (score 1):

Hikigaya asked for a girl's phone number in middle school, as mentioned in his flashback at 6:30 - 7:00 in episode 4. The number probably belongs to her, though he left her anonymous in his story in the anime (I haven't read the early volumes of the LN's). There's no Hanazawa Hanako in Volumes 7-10. For now, she remains in the back-burner of possible characters.

Comment: But keep in mind that (at least at one point) Hachiman had the phone numbers of multiple girls in his phone: he told that one story about how when he texted a number of them back in middle school, 40% replied the next morning saying "sorry I was asleep" or something; 30% ignored him altogether; and the remaining 30% got him a response from "a foreigner named 'Mailer Daemon'" (god that was hilarious). It could just be one of the girls from middle school, I guess, though the question then is of course, which one?

Comment: [OreGairu Wikia](http://yahari.wikia.com/wiki/Kaori_Orimoto#Trivia) says that `Orimoto is the only middle school classmate of Hachiman made known to the series`. This contradicts your assumption so it's possible that she's another person yet to be revealed